# How can I put DatePicker in ContextMenu in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, datepicker, swiftui, contextmenu

I want to put `DatePicker` in ContextMenu as MenuItem. I tried it as following code.
`Button` seems good but `DatePicker` doesn't. Can I do something like this? If yes how can I?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .contextMenu {
                Button("Delete") {
                    // some action
                }
                
                DatePicker("", selection: $selectedDate)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `ContextMenu` only supports `Button`s.

Note: `ContextMenu` is deprecated in iOS 14.2. Check out [Menu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu) instead.

Comment: I mean this `public func contextMenu<MenuItems>(@ViewBuilder menuItems: () -> MenuItems) -> some View where MenuItems : View`. This func is not deprecated.